# html markup in messages properties with placeholders - XSS potential

Tags: html, spring, localization, xss, html-escape

Given the message in a messages properties file:

`message = Change relation <strong>{0}</strong> -> <strong>{1}</strong> to <strong>{2}</strong> -> <strong>{3}</strong>?`

if the content of any of the placeholders is a user-influenced string, I need to html escape the message in order to prevent a potential XSS (I do that by using the `c:out` tag in my JSP templates, I guess I could use the htmlEscape-attribute of the `spring:message` tag as well, but I think there's no difference).

However by doing so, I corrupt the markup in the message, `<strong>` etc. which leads to the output:

`Change relation <strong>Peter</strong> -> <strong>Car</strong> to <strong>Carl</strong> -> <strong>Bus</strong>?`

I've already read the thread here [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225/how-can-i-refactor-html-markup-out-of-my-property-files) but it does not address XSS.

I am thinking about these options:

1) Simply replace all `<strong>` tags from the messages properties files with single quotes. Then there's no problem html escaping the entire message, with the drawback of a little less highlighting of the specific parts of the message.

2) Split the message into parts which allow for separate markup in the (JSP) template. This feels like much work just to get the markup right.

Am I missing something here? Which is the better option, or is there another option?

**Edit:** Without html-escaping the message is, like I want it to be, like this:

Change relation **Peter** -> **Car** to **Carl** -> **Bus**?

So the html-markup as in the messages.properties file is being rendered when displayed in the template.

When escaping, the message is like above, showing me the `<strong>` tags instead of rendering them.

Comment: Are you saying that it leads to the output: `&lt;strong&gt;Peter&lt;/strong&gt;`? Because your "corrupted" example is exactly the same as the original message as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've edited my question trying to clarify my situation some more.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If you look at the HTML (view source), you'll see that you are, in fact, sending `&lt;` to the client rather than `<`. So, I believe my answer still stands - let me know if it is unclear or if I am misinterpreting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going under the assumption that you are getting the following output:

> `Change relation &lt;strong&gt;Peter&lt;/strong&gt; -&gt; &lt;strong&gt;Car&lt;/strong&gt; to &lt;strong&gt;Carl&lt;/strong&gt; -&gt; &lt;strong&gt;Bus&lt;/strong&gt;`

It looks like you are escaping your entire HTML string rather than just the part that needs to be escaped.

You should escape each `{#}` value on its own, and then place it into the HTML. The general values you need to escape are: `<`, `>`, `'`, `"`, and `&`, but use an anti-xss library and templating system if you can.

Once you've escaped all the potentially dangerous parts, you can use something like `<c:out value="${msg}" escapeXml="false"/>`. This is not a language/framework I know, but you need some way to output the actual HTML vs the escaped version. Whatever way you prefer should be fine as long as you properly escape the untrusted part.

Comment: I agree on the part, that I should only escape the untrusted parts of the message.
That would leave me the option to escape the parameters *before* they are passed to the message and then, as you say not escape the message when rendering it.

Comment: Just FYI, I've solved my issue by replacing the markup in the properties file with single quotes.
But I am pretty sure, the way to go would be to simply escape the message parameters while passing them into the message, and then, render the message *without* html escaping.
Thanks @Gray!